# Observing NSWindow properties breaks when a window's delegate is set

Tags: cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nswindow, nsnotification

I'm observing the following notifications for a window:

- NSWindowDidMoveNotification
- NSWindowDidResizeNotification
- NSWindowDidChangeScreenNotification

I register as an observer in my `NSWindowController` subclass using the following code:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(persistedWindowPropertiesDidChange:)
                                                 name:<Notification Name>
                                               object:self.window];
```

I observed behavior that I haven't experienced before and was wondering why it was occurring.

If the window's delegate property is set to nil, everything works as expected (notifications are observed). However, if the window's delegate is set to an object, passing self.window for the `object` parameter of `-addObserver:selector:name:object:` causes the selector to never be called. If nil is passed for the object parameter, the selector is called for all windows (expected behavior). Why does setting the delegate of the window break the filtering by object behavior of the notification center? This is occurring on 10.11.6.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Are you setting the window's delegate to the same object as `self` in your code snippet?

Comment: No, the window's delegate was set to the app delegate as it is the object that creates the window controller and maintains a reference to it until it is closed. I was observing the window closing notification in the app delegate. In the code snippet `self` is the window controller subclass. I fixed the issue by making the app delegate observe window closing notifications for all windows (passing nil for the object) and removing the delegate from the window. The window controller subclass was then able to properly observe the move/resize/screen change notifications.

Comment: Usually the window controller is the delegate of its window.